# What is the sum of the series $\sum_{n = 1} ^ {\infty} \left( \sqrt[n]3 - \sqrt[n+1]3 \right)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> What is the sum of the series $$\sum_{n = 1} ^ {\infty} \left( \sqrt[n]3 - \sqrt[n+1]3 \right)\:?$$

I actually know that the answer is $2$, but I don't see how, so I would like to ask for some help with that. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Show that $\sum_{n=1}^N (\sqrt[n]{3} - \sqrt[n+1]{3}) = 3 - \sqrt[N+1]{3}$. Then think about how $\sqrt[N+1]{3}$ behaves as $N$ tends to infinity.